# How to find a random index in array A which value does not appear in array B?

Tags: arrays, swift

Let's say array A holds this:

```
[0, 1, 8, 3, 10, 6, 2]
```

And array B holds this:

```
[1, 2]
```

How can I generate a random index in array A which value does not appear in array B? Possible indexes in above example are:

```
0, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

But how to do this in Swift?

Comment: How large are the arrays? Is it guaranteed that such an index exists?

Comment: @MartinR Very small (~20 int values) and array B is always smaller or equal to array A and array B can only hold values array A is holding. I saw your comment on a answer, I am trying now to combine your comment and that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to work with Array elements and their indices, `enumerated()` can be a good tool:

```
var a = [0, 1, 8, 3, 10, 6, 2]
var b = [1, 2]
var possibleIndices = a.enumerated()
    .filter{!b.contains($0.element)}
    .map{$0.offset}
print(possibleIndices)
//->[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

(When `b` can be large, better make it a `Set`.)

And then:

(When we can assume `b` never holds all contents of `a`.)

```
var randomIndexToPossibleIndices = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(possibleIndices.count)))
var randomIndex = possibleIndices[randomIndexToPossibleIndices]
```

---

If the assumption above cannot be satisfied, `possibleIndices` can be empty. So you'd better make `randomIndex` Optional:

```
var randomIndex: Int? = nil
if !possibleIndices.isEmpty {
    var randomIndexToPossibleIndices = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(possibleIndices.count)))
    randomIndex = possibleIndices[randomIndexToPossibleIndices]
}
```

Thanks for Martin R.

Comment: Or flatMap: `let indices = a.enumerated().flatMap { bset.contains($0.element) ? nil : $0.offset }`

Comment: One should also check that `possibleIndices` is not empty. `arc4random_uniform(0)` returns `0`, which would not be a valid index in that case.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd have to generate a diff between the 2 arrays ( unless they're both extremely large, in which case randomly trying recursively might result in better performance ).

Then all you have to do is find a random index you'd like to use and access said element:

```
#if os(Linux)
    let j = Int(random() % ((count-1)))
#else
    let j = Int(Int(arc4random()) % ((count-1)))
#endif
```

Will give you a proper index

If you then use this index and the element to find original element in your array you'll have your result.

If in case your elements are integers, and thus collisions can occur the thing I'd do would be recursively finding it to solve your problem. Remember that this can result in slow performance.

Look into the functional programming part of collections in swift here:
[Swift Guide to map filter reduce](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/)

For instance you could use filter in the following way ( and I don't know if this is the best way ):

```
collection.filter {
  var found = false;
  for element in bCollection {
      if element == $0 {
          found = true;
      }
  }
  return !found; // Might be better to turn true/false thing around in the above code to slightly improve performance.
}
```

Comment: "First, you'd have to generate a diff between the 2 arrays " Yes, but how would I do that? The other answers only show me the values remaining when searching the differences, but I want the indexes. The arrays are small.

Comment: @J.Doe I ammended my answer to help you with that. Keep in mind some more advanced algorithms might result in better performance if you have huge collections. But for that you'd have to resort to some more advanced documentation and or libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, but I prefer the oneliner from OOper :)

Comment: @J.Doe He has the correct information to accept the answer of, as his answer is better in many ways. so it is good you did.

Answer (score 1):

How about working with sets?

```
let a = [0, 1, 8, 3, 10, 6, 2]
let b = [1, 2]

var setA = Set(a)
var setB = Set(b)

setA.subtract(setB)

var index: Int? = nil
if let first = setA.first {
    index = a.index(of: first)
}
// if index == nil no such index exists
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, but I prefer the oneliner from OOper :)

Comment: Where is the randomness here?

Comment: @MartinR A set is unordered, whether getting the first is 'random' (implementation defined) enough for OP is not clear. If better randomness is desired you'll have to combine parts of other solutions :-)

Comment: @J.Doe, @MartinR for a 'real' randomness one-liner (that can crash :-) ): `a.index(of: Array(Set(a).subtract(Set(b)))[arc4random_uniform(Set(a).subtract(Set(b)).count)])`, but seriously OOPer's answer is better.